# Split string with if condition - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my string:

`Question;;;;;The hybridization of the central carbon in CH3C≡N and the bond angle CCN are:: #####1`

I have split it using the below code -

**JS code:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Question;;;;;The hybridization of the central carbon in CH3C≡N and the bond angle CCN are:: #####1";
  var res = str.split(";;;;;");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I am getting is:

`Question,The hybridization of the central carbon in CH3C≡N and the bond angle CCN are:: #####1`

I want `Question` in a different variable and left over line in another variable, like:

```
var1 = Question 

var 2 = The hybridization of the central carbon in CH3C≡N and the bond angle CCN are:: #####1
```

and a **if** condition in **var2**, if it has `##### with some no. in the end`, then put it in var3.

Comment: `split` returns an array, so `res[0]` would be your `var1` and `res[1]` would be your `var2`

Comment: how about - and a if condition in var2, if it has ##### with some no. in the end, then put it in var3  and remove from var2 , can you provide working example in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @VLAZ said, split function returns array and you can access each element in different variables eg:

```js
var str = "Question;;;;;The hybridization of the central carbon in CH3C≡N and the bond angle CCN are:: #####1";
var res = str.split(";;;;;");

var q = res[0];
var text = res[1];

console.log(q);
console.log(text);
```

You can directly add new lines by using join() function on array:

```js
var str = "Question;;;;;The hybridization of the central carbon in CH3C≡N and the bond angle CCN are:: #####1";
var res = str.split(";;;;;").join("\n\n")
console.log(res);
```

From comments, i think you have to use Regex:

```js
var str = "Question;;;;;The hybridization of the central carbon in CH3C≡N and the bond angle CCN are:: #####1";
var res = str.split(";;;;;");
var var3 = '';
if(res[1].match(/[\#]{5}/)){
var3 = res[1].split(/[\#]{5}/)[1];
var2 = res[1].split(/[\#]{5}/)[0];
}
else{
var3 = '';}
console.log(var3);
console.log(var2);
```

```js
var str = "Question;;;;;The hybridization of the central carbon in CH3C≡N and the bond angle CCN are:: #####1";
var { groups :{ question , qno }} = /(?:\;{5})(?<question>.*?)(?:\#{5})(?<qno>\d+)/.exec(str);
console.log(qno);
console.log(question);
```

Comment: you missed this part - and a if condition in var2, if it has ##### with some no. in the end, then put it in var3 and remove from var2

Comment: Okay, you will need to split again. Try edited answer..

Comment: and remove `#####`+some no. from var2, how do we do that

Comment: Again edited...

Comment: Why split twice instead of doing a single split by regex?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function myFunction() {
  var str = "Question;;;;;The hybridization of the central carbon in CH3C≡N and the bond angle CCN are:: #####1";
  var res = str.split(";;;;;");

  //res[0] contains 'Question' and res[1] will contain rest of sentence
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[0];
}
```